# Closed a dupe but with the wrong Q&A, please close again

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53250/can-i-prevent-a-permanent-from-becomeing-the-target-of-a-spell-ability-by-giving) is a dupe of [that question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28855/do-abilities-like-becomes-the-target-of-a-spell-or-ability-sacrifice-it-happe), but I closed it with an answer that wasn't the actual dupe. I re-opened it but now can't close it again.

Comment: Voted to close it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – I've dupehammered it.

In the future, you could [edit the duplicate list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/295232) instead of reopening it.